# How to exclude value in a sum(case) statement where one value matches a value in a different attribute in a different row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a sum(case) query that will return a value of 1 for all ‘positive’ labels defined as the following ('F', 'B', 'Z').  However, for rows where case = ‘D23’, I’d like to return a value of 0, UNLESS the MATCHED attribute for that row equal to the ID of a record with a negative LABEL('W').

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN T1.case in 'D23' and T2.PASS = 'Y' THEN 0
  ELSE 1 END) "temp1" FROM incoming.stuff T1
  join doesit.pass T2
  on T1.ID = T2.ID
  where LABEL in ('F', 'B', 'Z');


T1
ID | SID  | MATCHED| CASE|LABEL
100|      | 300    | D23 | F
200|      |        | A01 | B
300| 100  |        | M99 | W
400|      |        | A01 | B
500|      |        | A01 | Z
600|      |        | A01 | B
700|      |        | A01 | B
800| 777  |        | M99 | W
900|      |        | A01 | B
999|      |        | A01 | Z


T2
ID | PASS|
100|   Y |  
200|   Y |  
300|   Y |  
400|   Y |  
500|   Y |  
600|   Y |  
700|   Y |  
800|   Y |  
900|   Y |  
999|   Y |
```

So when I run the above query on this the SUM value returned is 7.  Since row 100 has a matched value of 300, and row ID 300 is a ‘negative’ value, I’d like that row to return be included in the sum as ‘1’, for a total of ‘8’.

Comment: `CASE WHEN T1.case in ('D','2','3' ) and T2.PASS = 'Y'`? Or you mean `T1.case = 'D23'`? Try to not use reserved words as identifiers names

Comment: I am a bit lost.  Your query references two tables.  You have shown one table.  It is not the result set, because that is simply a number.  Then you say you want to count something "and return a value of 0".  Is that for the entire count?  Or do you just want to filter out a row given certain conditions?

Comment: Sorry, I have revised the dataset to reflect what both tables look like.  I'd like the output to be a number based on the sum that fit the critera.  So I think maybe I can explain it a bit better like this.  If the row has a D23 and pass= 'Y' then I'd like the value to be '0', UNLESS there is a matched value that is equal to another row's ID that has a negative label (label = W).  When that happens, I'd like that rows value to be '1' in regards to the sum.

Comment: Are you really looking for something specific to the fixed value D23; or actually anywhere that matched is set? If the latter then could there be more than one level of hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use magical CONNECT BY clause to achieve the result -

```
WITH TAB AS (SELECT T1.ID, SID, MATCHID, "CASE", T2.PASS, CONNECT_BY_ROOT(LABEL) LABEL
             FROM T1
             INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
             CONNECT BY PRIOR MATCHID = T1.ID)
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN "CASE" in 'D23' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
  FROM TAB
 WHERE LABEL IN ('F', 'B', 'Z')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f66aa8f5b05d3f94f091ed376851077a) is the fiddle for your reference.